# Changing scope variables on events from a separates view's controller in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say you have a login system, where the nav is in on the "main" view which never changes, it also contains a placeholder ng-model for the user's name:

```
$scope.userName = Session.userName();
```

However, this is being assigned as soon as the page loads, and that's bad. How would I make it so the login controller changes this variable on the maincontroller as soon as the $http request returns successful?

```
$scope.login = function() { 
        $http.post('http://restfulservice.com', 
            angular.toJson($scope.loginUser))
    .success( function (data, status, headers, config) {
            if (data.out) {
            var data= JSON.parse(data.out);
            Session.userName(data.Nombre);
            Session.memorizarId(datos.idCliente);
            Session.memorizarLogged(true);
      }
```

Comment: using service would be better option..just update service variable will reflect everywhere..NOTE service data should be in object..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at angularJs eventing mechanism `$broadcast` and `$emit`.

Once the login is successful you can broadcast a message and whichever controller is listening to this message it will get the broadcasted message and act accordingly.

```
$scope.login = function() { 
        $http.post('http://restfulservice.com', 
            angular.toJson($scope.loginUser))
    .success( function (data, status, headers, config) {
            if (data.out) {
            var data= JSON.parse(data.out);
            Session.userName(data.Nombre);
            Session.memorizarId(datos.idCliente);
            Session.memorizarLogged(true);

            //broadcast the message passing the user info optionally
            $rootScope.$broadcast('user-logged-in', data);
      }
```

Inside maincontroller

```
$rootScope.$on('user-logged-in', function (user) {
  $scope.userName = Session.userName();
  //Or using the broadcasted user object
  $scope.userName = user.Nombre;
});
```

From angularJs documentation:

> The event life cycle starts at the scope on which $broadcast was
>   called. All listeners listening for name event on this scope get
>   notified. Afterwards, the event propagates to all direct and indirect
>   scopes of the current scope and calls all registered listeners along
>   the way. The event cannot be canceled.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: Just one question, because I've seen these events being written before, but what does 'user-logged-in' do? Where does it come from and what's the use of it? I can understand $stateChangestart going in its place, but this seems custom.

Comment: `user-logged-in` is just a name given to the event so that anybody who wants to subscribe to this event can use this event name.